# Should Hibernate bidirectional associations be avoided?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

In a Spring/Hibernate based project, we have a one-to-many relationship between two entities. Required operations are:

- find the child's parent;
- find the parent's children;
- when parent is being removed, we also need to remove the children;
- mass-create the children.

We came up with two ways to implement this.

1. [**Bidirectional** association](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-bidirectional): child entity has `@ManyToOne` column linking it to parent, and *the parent has `@OneToMany` lazy-loaded collection of children*. All above operations can be performed in the model:

   ```
   child.getParent();
   parent.getChildren(); //lazy loading
   session.delete(parent); //cascade removal of the children does the trick here
   session.save(parent); //cascade persist created the children
   ```
2. **Unidirectional** association: child entity has `@ManyToOne` column linking it to parent, but *the parent does not have any link to children*. Most operations should be performed in service methods:

   ```
   child.getParent(); //still in the model
   Collection<Child> findChildren(Parent parent); //service method in ChildService
   void deleteChildren(Parent parent); //service method in ChildService
   void createChild(Parent parent, ... childAttributes); //service method in ChildService invoked for each new child.
   ```

The first approach seems to be easier to implement (you can reuse Hibernate cascading functionality) but some of us see the bidirectional associations as a potential cause of problems.

**What should be a better design choice? Are there any well-known problems, performance or design, created by the bidirectional approach?**

Comment: Do you know of a source that explains how to get lazyloading to work? I had trouble with this in a JSF project.

Comment: "some of us see the bidirectional associations as a potential cause of problems" - can you name these potential problems?

Answer (score 4):

If your queries do the same thing as the queries executed behind the scene by Hibernate when it lazy-loads the children, I don't see what you gain by not simplyuse a OneToMany association.

If you know what you're doing, and what each method call on your entity means in terms of queries to the database, you shouldn't have any problem with mapped collections. Sometimes it's wise to traverse them, sometimes it's better to use an ad-hoc query to avoid too many round-trips to the database. The key is to understand what happens.

Having an asociation can also be very helpful just to be able to navigate through it in HQL queries, not necessarily to call the associated getter.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @JB Nizet says it nearly all, just one more thing: Looking at the method call samples you posted, the bidirectional method will probably make your business logic code somewhat more readable.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're in a situation where lazy loading really works for you, I haven't seen a real problem with bidirectional relationships. I once worked on a Flex application where Hibernate was used and the bidirectional relationships would often cause the entire database to be downloaded when data was serialized to the client.

YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 
That should be avoided as much as possible. if you really think, that is your requirement, then only use bi-directional. eg. Emp and Dept, every emp has one department, but department have many employee. emp must knows about his department, but it is not  mandatory that, department should also know their department.

Comment: This seems more like a comment, rather than an answer.